What would the Big Crunch theoretically look/feel like?
In the Big Crunch theory, the expansion of the universe reverses, resulting in all matter contracting into a single point. Imagine you are alive at the time of this event. What would the sky look like? Would you feel anything? Basically, what would the general experience of it be like? If you die in the process, also consider how it would be different if you are immortal (ie. just observing, whether you have a physical body or not).

what do you mean "at the time"?  If the expansion reverses, initially things are pretty normal..As density (and temperature) rises biology becomes physics but life will long before have ceased to exist.

I once wrote an article Big Bang — an eyewitness account. If you read it backwards, you get a description of how the Big Crunch would feel :) (associated to the article I wrote a Python code that returns various properties of the Universe as a function of time after the Big Bang / before the Big Crunch. You can find it on github/universe-timeline).

Inhomogeneities would be growing more and more rapidly in the last billion years so the end will not be homogeneous like the beginning was.  The random motions would delay the final collapse until a growing event horizon swallows everything and everyone.  Background radiation would disintegrate everything, but clumps would be bigger than the beginning.
